# When I run raspi-config the cursor goes to the next line and freezes

Tags: vnc, raspi-config, raspbian-stretch

I'm running headless Raspberry Pi Zero W with SSH. I'm trying to get VNC running so I can get to the GUI. My understanding is that I need to get `raspi-config` to run so that I can set VNC to "yes".

When I attempt to open `sudo rasp-config`, my cursor moves to the next line like it's working but it freezes and never goes any further.

I found the command `sudo bash -x raspi-config` on a GitHub post. When I run that the text of the menu comes back in the response, however, it's just text.

I've re-flashed the OS a couple times and see the same result. It seems based on the output from the above command that the menu tries to come back. Perhaps this is something in my PuTTY setup that I've messed up that's preventing this from working? FYI, I'm also attempting this from two completely different machines and see the same result in each.

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling PuTTY to no avail.

Anyone have an idea what will get me going?

Comment: How to use raspi-config > https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

Comment: For once connect keyboard and display to RPi and run raspi-config this way.

Answer (score 0):

The `RealVNC` included with Raspbian is designed to mirror a screen attached to the Pi (on RealVNC customised viewer).

It **IS** possible to to configure `RealVNC` to work without a screen, but you would be better to use `tightvncserver`, which creates a new virtual screen, and works with ALL VNC Viewers.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this failed as well. In each case it appears that I connect however the screen is black.

Comment: You can create a virtual screen with `RealVNC`